# Visual Studio test machine debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a mixed C# and CLI C++ project that is throwing an exception from C++ on Windows XP test machines.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of a light tool (short of installing Visual Studio itself) that I could install on the test machine to identify the location of the exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Windows Debugger. It is free, and can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

There are many sites and books detailing how to use Windows Debugger. Microsoft provides the following site for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=VS.85).aspx

http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html has a list of common WinDbg commands.

It is very useful, can be installed on test machines, and can be used to read minidumps, unlike Visual Studio 2008 and older versions.

To generate a dump at any time, start task manager on the test machine, right click on the application you want a dump from, and select "Create Dump File".

If you have a dump or minidump from your application, you can use the WinDbg.exe (Windows Debugger) to get a stack trace using the command "!analyze -v".

Comment: Visual Studio can read minidumps and has been able to do that for several versions.

Comment: I know VS 2008 and older can't. I'll update my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Hm - maybe it depends on the version of VS2008 (Professional, Express or what ever). I have read and debugged minidumps with VS since VS2005, maybe even VS2003 - not sure about the last one, though.

Comment: Our VS2008 Pro editions at work couldn't read the minidumps coming out of our customers set ups nor from our test machines. I had to use Windows Debugger for that. Perhaps VS simply can't handle as compact mini-dumps as Windows Debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget the remote debugger! I find this ideal, assuming you can connect to your dev box over the net. If the dev box is in a different room, use remote desktop from the test machine.

[Instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)

[And see my answer here with more tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981190/180326)